# Pandas DataReader does not recognise % as part of the string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datareader

The following code is an attempt to call DAX historical index from google finance, however the % sign is converted to %25 when the function actually calls for "INDEXDB%3ADAX". How can I preserve the % sign without the conversion.

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)  
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)
f = web.DataReader("INDEXDB%3ADAX", 'google', start, end)
```

Returns: IOError: after 3 tries, Google did not return a 200 for url 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=**INDEXDB%253ADAX**&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013&output=csv'

Comment: It is called [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or percent-encoding, and is required. [A % is encoded as %25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_the_percent_character).

Answer (score 0):

i don't think the encoding is the problem, the data simply is not available in google as csv format.

in browser post links,

```
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXDB:DAX&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXDB%3ADAX&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013
```

both return html page without problem,

```
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXDB:DAX&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013&output=csv
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXDB%3ADAX&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013&output=csv
```

both return 404 not found.

basically, the data is not available for download as csv.

Comment: This is weird though. Because if I called for a stock price, like Google's, "f = web.DataReader("GOOG", 'google', start, end), it returns a pandas data frame.

Comment: Google buys data from other data vendors and there are restrictions whether Google can make it available for download. It's not technical.

Comment: I see. Thank you!